# Android:Is it possible to do all updating tasks with AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have used *background service* in  for updating tasks like playing with web server frequent times(sending Geo-Location data or send/get web data time-wise) in my android apps and also I have faced many problems(slow process, application hang) for this.

But In my current application I have used the AlarmManager followed by PendingIntents for some tasks which worked well.
So I think its good if I replace each updating tasks which use service with AlarmManager followed by PendingIntents.

Is it the right way or I am going doing a big mistake ?

All kind of suggestions are appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services and alarms scheduled with `AlarmManager` serve different but complementary purposes at times. When you schedule an alarm with one of the `set` methods, the alarm will be triggered at the specified time and you should handle it on a `BroadcastReceiver`. This means that your handling has to be responsive and cannot have asynchronous operations. [According to the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle):

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active. (...) Anything that requires asynchronous operation is not
>   available, because you will need to return from the function to handle
>   the asynchronous operation, but at that point the BroadcastReceiver is
>   no longer active and thus the system is free to kill its process
>   before the asynchronous operation completes.

In case you want to handle more complex operations, it is advised to start a service for doing so. Even if you use the more recently available `goAsync()` call on the receiver, you are still expected to [be responsive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#goAsync%28%29):

> This does not change the expectation of being relatively responsive to the broadcast (finishing it within 10s)

So it ultimately depends on what you are trying to achieve, when to use each of these or combine their use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't tell that using Alaram Manager is a big mistake..

Right now to run the background services there are only few options upon which the easy and partially reliable one would be AlarmManager.

Though sometimes the `Alarm Manager is not 100% reliable` on looking into other categories for doing these operations (like `Asynchronous Thread` and `delay looping` techniques) are much more complex and not that much reliable to do the background services.

When we compare the pros and cons of the techniques needed for background services AlarmManager wins the race.

**I prefer** `AlarmManager` would be the good option for these kind of background services upon thinking the options open right now to complete the tasks in background.

Hope that Google will comeup with a better solution to handle the background services.

Comment: this is good, but I think you didn't understand my question perfectly. i want to use Alarmmanager and Pendingintent for the base of my updating tasks, where i used service before. i think without service we can do these kind of tasks only through alarmmanager, pendingintent and a broadcastreceiver.